# PHP : Select an option inside a php loop

Tags: php

I have the following where it generates options from the database

```
foreach($categories as $rowcat)
{echo '<option value="'.$rowcat->catname.'">'.$rowcat->catname.'</option>';
}
```

I need to select an option when loading, so how i'm gonna insert like

```
selected="Office"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$opt = "Office";
foreach($categories as $rowcat){                   
    if( $row->catname == $opt ) {
    echo '<option value="'.$row->catname.'" selected="selected">'.$rowcat->catname.'</option>';                
   }
   else {
    echo '<option value="'.$row->catname.'">'.$rowcat->catname.'</option>';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($categories as $rowcat){                   

echo '<option value="'.$rowcat->catname.'" '.($rowcat->catname=='Office') ? 'selected="selected"' : ''.'>'.$rowcat->catname.'</option>';                
}
```